# Last Row Paste to different Worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I am trying to paste info on the last row of a different worksheet.  I already have the info copied and this macro is just to paste it.  With the code that I have now, I am getting an error that says "Paste Method of Worksheet Class Failed"  how can I fix this?

here is the code:

```
Windows("m.xlsx").Activate
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D45").Select
Windows("d.xlsx").Activate
```

Comment: try to fully qualify your `Cells` object, you are missing the `Worksheets` object. For example `Workbooks("m.xlsx").Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(...).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

Excel is known to clear the clipboard and hence you should put the copy command one line before you paste.

So in your case the copy command will go before

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Also please avoid the use of `.Select/Activate`. Please read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set thisWb = Workbooks("d.xlsx")
    Set thatWb = Workbooks("m.xlsx")

    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet
    With thatWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        '~~> Find last Row to paste
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        '~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet
        '~~> Replace A1:A10 with the relevant range that you are trying to copy
        thisWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy .Range("A" & lRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, what I'm trying to do is sort of like that but since I am inexperienced with VBA, I was combining this macro with a previous macro that ended with copying a group of filtered data.  My ultimate goal is to copy from "d" to the last row of "m"

Comment: Copy what from "D" ?

Comment: Some filtered data, the code for that looks like this:

  `ActiveSheet.Range("$J$12:$O$64").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="No"
  
  ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21

            Rows("16:16").Select

         Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 
         Selection.Copy`

Comment: What is the logic? Why are you going to 16th row and copying from that row?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake.  That should be:  `Cells.Select`

Comment: `Sorry that was a mistake. That should be: Cells.Select – acabr136 23 secs ago` Then why the autofilter? What exactly are you trying to copy? Can you give us a little more detail?